# How to delete a file from the remote machine automatically when ending an SSH session to it with MobaXTerm?

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I'm using MobaXTerm to SSH to a remote machine. Is there any way to delete a file from the remote machine automatically when ending an SSH session to it with MobaXTerm? Thank you.

Comment: as much as I remember there is only a "execute script after connect" option. if you need to delete something from one particular server on logout you could look into the bash_logout if you use bash on the remote server.

Comment: @Zina, thank you very much. Maybe I should define a special environment variable when login with MobaXTerm, check in bash_logout if it's the MobaXTerm SSH session, and delete corresponding file if yes? In this way, other SSH session won't be affected.

Comment: sounds good if it will suit your needs :) and test it thoroughly